# SMCalloutView with MapBox

Tags: objective-c, github, annotations, mapbox

While implementing SMCalloutView i added SMCalloutView.h and SMCalloutView.m. Im also using the Mapbox SDK when when trying to build i get this error:

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_SMCalloutBackgroundView in:
   path/Objects-normal/i386/SMCalloutView.o
    path/Mapbox.framework/Mapbox(SMCalloutView.o)
ld: 19 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

So MapBox is already implementing SMCalloutView or am I wrong? If so how can I use it then?

Also the left accesoryview gets clipped in the MapBox Callout View. I'm trying to replicate SMCalloutViews example: https://github.com/nfarina/calloutview/blob/master/SampleAssets/CalloutScreenshot.png with MapBox but the blue area doesnt take all the place on the left side. Instead a small stroke of white is visible on the left, top and bottom.

Comment: I do have same question ! Getting "duplicate symbol error" for x86_64 architecture.  Did you solved the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Mapbox is already using SMCalloutView internally. This is a pretty classic result of Objective-C not having namespacing like some other languages. I would recommend you remove your custom added version of the library and just make use of Mapbox's directly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you take a look at my edit? It's a whole other question but still about SMCalloutView.

Comment: Hmm, not sure why that is. Have you tried the latest release version of SMCalloutView? I'd also suggest filing a GitHub issue in that project with a screenshot, as that sounds like a bug from intended behavior.